# How to use the last valid modelValue if a model becomes invalid?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I'm working on an application that saves changes automatically when the user changes something, for example the value of an input field. I have written a `autosave` directive that is added to all form fields that should trigger save events automatically.

**template:**

```
   <input ng-model="fooCtrl.name" autosave>
   <input ng-model="fooCtrl.email" autosave>
```

**directive:**

```
  .directive('autosave', ['$parse', function  ($parse) {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        function saveIfModelChanged () {
          // save object containing name and email to server ...
        }

        ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
          saveIfModelChanged();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

So far, this all works fine for me. However, when I add validation into the mix, for example validating the input field to be a valid email address, the modelValue is set to `undefined` as soon as the viewValue is changed to an invalid email address.

What I would like to do is this:  Remember the last valid modelValue and use this when autosaving. If the user changes the email address to be invalid, the object containing `name` and `email` should still be saved to the server. Using the current valid `name` and the last valid `email`.

I started out by saving the last valid modelValue like this:

**template with validation added:**

```
   <input type="email" ng-model="fooCtrl.name" autosave required>
   <input ng-model="fooCtrl.email" autosave required>
```

**directive with saving lastModelValue:**

```
  .directive('autosave', ['$parse', function  ($parse) {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        var lastModelValue;

        function saveIfModelChanged () {

          // remeber last valid modelValue
          if (ngModel.$valid) {
             lastModelValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
          }

          // save object containing current or last valid
          // name and email to server ...
        }

        ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
          saveIfModelChanged();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

My question is, how to use `lastModelValue` while saving, but preserving the invalid value in the view?

**EDIT:**

Another possibility, [as suggested by Jugnu below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32629886/60518), would be wrapping and manipulating the build in validators.

I tried to following: wrap all existing validators and remember the last valid value, to restore it if validations fails:

```
Object.keys(ngModel.$validators).forEach(function(validatorName, index) {
    var validator = ngModel.$validators[validatorName];
    ngModel.$validators[validatorName] = createWrapper(validatorName, validator, ngModel);
});

function createWrapper(validatorName, validator, ngModel){

  var lastValid;

  return function (modelValue){

    var result = validator(modelValue);

    if(result) {
      lastValid = modelValue;
    }else{
        // what to do here? maybe asign the value like this:
      // $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, lastValid);
    }

    return result;
  };
}
```

But I'm not sure how to continue with this approach either. Can I set the model value without AngularJS kicking in and try to validate that newly set value?

Comment: Given that you are also developing the backend of your app, I would consider outsourcing the whole problem into the backend. If the backend would happen to be node.js, I would just update those values `v` to my database for which `v!==undefined` hold and save myself some working hours. I understand that you might not be able to do this or do this project for learning purposes, just my thoughs about dev efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a simple directive that serves as a wrapper on the *ng-model* directive and will keep always the latest valid model value. It's called *valid-ng-model* and should replace the usage of *ng-model* on places where you want to have the latest valid value.

I've created an example use case [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0phMqzj5YqPKiqo0eUYa?p=preview), I hope you will like it. Any ideas for improvements are welcomed.

This is the implementation code for *valid-ng-model* directive.

```
app.directive('validNgModel', function ($compile) {
  return {
      terminal: true,
      priority: 1000,
      scope: {
        validNgModel: '=validNgModel'
      },
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        // NOTE: add ngModel directive with custom model defined on the isolate scope
        scope.customNgModel = angular.copy(scope.validNgModel);
        element.attr('ng-model', 'customNgModel'); 
        element.removeAttr('valid-ng-model');

        // NOTE: recompile the element without this directive
        var compiledElement = $compile(element)(scope);
        var ngModelCtrl = compiledElement.controller('ngModel');

        // NOTE: Synchronizing (inner ngModel -> outside valid model)
        scope.$watch('customNgModel', function (newModelValue) {
          if (ngModelCtrl.$valid) {
            scope.validNgModel = newModelValue;
          }
        });

        // NOTE: Synchronizing (outside model -> inner ngModel)
        scope.$watch('validNgModel', function (newOutsideModelValue) {
          scope.customNgModel = newOutsideModelValue;
        });
      }
    };
});
```

> Edit: directive implementation without isolate scope: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3sCddqzHYy99XcIh8U5f?p=preview).

Comment: I played around with the plunker and it looks very promising! I'am gonna try to integrate it in our application and get back with the results. Do you think it would be problematic/hard to merge the `autosave` and `valid-ng-model` directives?

Comment: Thanks, I am glad that you liked it. For merging the two directive it's not a problem but IMHO they are about two different concerns that I don't like to be mixed. But if you think that it would be better like that then feel free to merge them, I can help you for that too.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I can manage to merge the directives. However, I wonder about another aspect: You directive creates an isolated scope which neither ngModel nor my autosave directive does. Would it be possible without an isolated scope? Do we have to asign `customNgModel` to the scope to begin with?

Comment: I'm actually facing different problems because of that isolated scope: 1. inside my autosave directive I have to use `scope.$parent.$eval(...);` now, instead of `scope.$eval(...);`, so I would have to search both the current scope and the parent scope depending on using `valid-ng-model` or `ng-model` 2. bootstrap-ui's datepicker-popup stops working when changing `ng-model` to `valid-ng-model`. 3. `ng-disabled="foo.enabled"` stops working when changing `ng-model="foo.title"` to `valid-ng-model="foo.title"`

Comment: The basic idea in my approach is to bind the ng-model directive to some inner model so I can control the values that are passed to my outer(real) model while keeping it's functionality. That is the reason why the directive needs new scope which does not need to be isolated. Here is the directive implemented with new scope that prototypicaly inherits from it's parent. It should solve the #1 and #3 issues that you have, for the #2 I'm not sure and you should try. Tell me what you think, if it works for you I will update my answer. Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/3sCddqzHYy99XcIh8U5f?p=preview

Comment: @TimBüthe, I've updated the answer with the latest implementation of valid-ng-model directive. If you're happy with the provided solution I would suggest you to handle the bounty points as reward before time goes up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are sending the entire object for each field modification, you have to keep the last valid state of that *entire* object somewhere. Use case I have in mind:

1. You have a valid object `{ name: 'Valid', email: 'Valid' }`.
2. You change the name to invalid; the `autosave` directive placed at the name input knows its own last valid value, so the correct object gets sent.
3. You change the email to invalid too. The `autosave` directive placed at the email input knows its own last valid value but NOT that of name. If the last known good values are not centralized, an object like `{ name: 'inalid', email: 'Valid' }` will be sent.

So the suggestion:

1. Keep a sanitized copy of the object you are editing. By sanitized I mean that any invalid initial values should be replaced by valid pristine ones (e.g. zeros, nulls etc). Expose that copy as a controller member, e.g. `fooCtrl.lastKnowngood`.
2. Let `autosave` know the last known good state, e.g. as:

   ```
   <input ng-model="fooCtrl.email" autosave="fooCtrl.lastKnowngood" required />
   ```
3. Keep the last known good local value in that object; utilize the `ng-model` expression, e.g. as:

   ```
   var lastKnownGoodExpr = $parse(attrs.autosave);
   var modelExpr = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

   function saveIfModelChanged () {
       var lastKnownGood = lastKnownGoodExpr(scope);

       if (ngModel.$valid) {
           // trick here; explanation later
           modelExpr.assign({fooCtrl: lastKnownGood}, ngModel.$modelValue);
       }

       // send the lastKnownGood object to the server!!!
   }
   ```
4. Send the `lastKnownGood` object.

*The trick, its shortcomings and how can it be improved:* When setting the local model value to the `lastKnownGood` object you use a context object different than the current scope; this object assumes that the controller is called `fooCtrl` (see the line `modelExpr.assign({fooCtrl: lastKnownGood}, ...)`). If you want a more general directive, you may want to pass the root as a different attribute, e.g.:

```
<input ng-model="fooCtrl.email" autosave="fooCtrl.lastKnowngood" required
    autosave-fake-root="fooCtrl" />
```

You may also do some parsing of the `ng-model` expression yourself to determine the first component, e.g. substring 0 → 1st occurence of the dot (again simplistic).

Another shortcoming is how you handle more complex paths (in the general case), e.g. `fooCtrl.persons[13].address['home'].street` - but that seems not to be your use case.

---

By the way, this:

```
ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
    saveIfModelChanged();
});
```

can be simplified as:

```
ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(saveIfModelChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the suggestions! That makes me think: If I start to fiddle with the model expression, I could create a proxy for the original object. I would then set values to the proxy if the original model gets invalid and send the proxy object to the server.

Comment: That seems close to the idea and could work as well, if I am getting it right - some example would help.

Answer (score 2):

Angular default validators will only assign value to model if its valid email address.To overcome that you will need to override default validators.

For more reference see : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#modifying-built-in-validators

You can create a `directive` that will assign invalide model value to some scope variable and then you can use it.

I have created a small demo for email validation but you can extend it to cover all other validator.

Here is fiddle : http://plnkr.co/edit/EwuyRI5uGlrGfyGxOibl?p=preview

Comment: wrapping and manipulating the build in validators seems like a good alternative. I tried to go down this path but stuck. Could you take a look at my edit to the question please? Do you have any further tips?

Comment: I don't see this as an option, overriding the validators will mean that they will need to return validation success even if the validation is not successful in order to retain the model value. That would break their functionality. 
This line is taken from the source code for ngModelCtrl and is executed after all validators are run: 
ctrl.$modelValue = allValid ? modelValue : undefined;